# Cannot open include file: 'iProxyTrans.h' - old Directshow project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, directx, directshow

I inherited a project that used old opencv, directx and directshow libraries and I'm trying to be able to compile it on a current Windows 7 VS 2010 machine.

Two of the includes that are causing problems are as follows:

```
#include <iProxyTrans.h>
#include <ProxyTransuids.h>
```

How can I get this to compile?  Are these files simply non-existant now?  I tried searching my computer and I could not find it.  I have the latest DirectX SDK and Windows SDK.  I am also using OpenCV 2.3.1.

*edit* If I comment these out, I get things such as:

```
1>someclass.cpp(126): error C2065: 'CLSID_ProxyTransform' : undeclared identifier
1>someclass.cpp(132): error C2065: 'IProxyTransform' : undeclared identifier
1>someclass.cpp(132): error C2065: 'pProxyTrans' : undeclared identifier
1>someclass.cpp(133): error C2065: 'IID_IProxyTransform' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Comment tham out and post compiler errors would would get then. I don't remeeber them to be related to `DirectShow`, I don't see them in `DirectX SDK` includes either. It looks like those are related to `OpenCV`.

Comment: @Roman R. That might be the case as well.  It is an opencv project.  I just hadn't recalled seeing them in opencv :)  I added the errors to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where it comes from: [ProxyTransuids.h](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/180018/ProxyTransuids.h__html), from OpenCV

```
//                        Intel License Agreement
//                For Open Source Computer Vision Library
```

Comment: Why is it not being found by standard OpenCV includes?  I am using the OpenCV 2.3.1 'superpack' for Windows found on the opencv website.

Comment: As a guess, it might be an extremely old version - the files are 7+ years old.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I expected.  There is no obvious replacement for these files?  I'd rather not be stuck using old versions of opencv.